# MySQL ORDER BY Send first to last

Tags: mysql, sql, list, sql-order-by

I managed to properly order my list using [this trick](http://www.mpopp.net/2006/06/sorting-of-numeric-values-mixed-with-alphanumeric-values/), using UNSIGNED variable but the output has a single issue, it places the only entry starting with a letter before the digit entries. (sorting by strings)

My current output using this SQL Statement `ORDER BY CAST(reason AS UNSIGNED), reason` (where "reason" are strings) is

```
Unknown reason
1- blablabla
2- blebleble
3- bliblibli
4- blobloblo
5- blublublu
6- blyblybly
```

I wish the "Unknown reason" which is the only string not starting with a digit to be at the bottom, therefore throwing the first result received to the bottom of the list.

Comment: `order by reason = 'Unknown', reason`?

Comment: Possibly - ORDER BY IF(reason = 'Unknown reason',99999,CAST(reason AS UNSIGNED)), reason. (You might need a bigger no. than 99999 depending on the max no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple keys to the order by, including expressions:

```
order by (left(reason, 1) between '0' and '9') desc,
         reason
```

The first condition evaluates to true when the condition starts with a digit, this is treated as a 1 and will go to the top.  The rest of reasons will go to the bottom.

Comment: I made it to work after all, i simply forgot the "desc" yesterday. Thanks mate you're a real bro :')